# Как взять значение к public partial class Main : Form от public solve(для примера)

Tags: c#, winforms, классы, события

Привет всем.
В кратце расскажу, есть приложение на winforms. Создаю button, и делаю событие на button1___click.  Этот button1_click создается в классе **public partial class Main**.

Еще есть у меня другой **class** Solve, там описаны переменные со значениями(this.a1=3,this.a2=2).

Вопрос: Как взять значения от **class Solve** и применить их в внутри button1_click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, один из вариантов, это реализовать класс Solve в том же пространстве имен, в котором находится главный класс приложения, после главного класса, а переменные класса Solve описать, как статические, т.е принадлежащие непосредственно самому классу Пример:

```
namespace Lol
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
...
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int solve_var = Solve.a;
    }
...
}

public class Solve
{
    public static int a = 10;
    public static int b = 20;
}

}
```

Comment: solve. (методы equals и referenceequals только)

Comment: а все берет значение, спасибо. А почему при вводе текстбокс значение 12, при выводе на excel в ячейке А0 выводит "System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: 12"

Answer (score 0):

Т.е. создать экземпляр класса? Тогда вот так:

```
Solve solve = new Solve();
```

По ходу создать метод(ы) в этом самом классе Solve, например getVar(), который(е) "отдают" эти данные и вызывать их:

```
solve.getVar();
```

Если только я правильно понял, что имелось ввиду.

Comment: извините не то...